# Reassign NaN based on column name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with several NaN values like so:

```
   first  second
0    1.0     3.0
1    2.0     NaN
2    NaN     5.0
```

and another with lookup values:

```
        fill
second   200
first    100
```

Is there a way to replace the NaN values with the fill values based on the column name to get this?:

```
   first  second
0    1.0     3.0
1    2.0     200
2    100     5.0
```

This is just an example, as I'm trying to do it on a much larger dataframe.  I know that I can rearrange the fields in the dataframes so that the indices match up and I could use pd.where, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make the match just based on column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for this